# runAction animation crash problem - what's missing

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Need a little help with a Cocos2d problem.

I am running a animations from the same sprite sheet and need the sprite to play a different 
animation when it is moving left to right and, up and down.

Iv'e tried a few different methods to get this to happen, the code below should be the nearest version, and it should work. But, it just crashes now (probably a memory leak).

The animation code I'm using originally comes from the great tutorials from the http://www.raywenderlich.com blog site.

Here is the snippet of code that I am having crashed with.
Can anyone give me any pointers as to what is missing?

thx
Richg

```
#import "HelloWorldScene.h"

// HelloWorld implementation
@implementation HelloWorld
@synthesize gameMan = _gameMan;
@synthesize moveAction = _moveAction;
@synthesize walkAction = _walkAction;
@synthesize walkAction2 = _walkAction2;


+(id) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
HelloWorld *layer = [HelloWorld node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{

if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)] )) {

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]    addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"gameMan.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode   batchNodeWithFile:@"gameMan.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    //Loop thru frames and add a cache of the frames
    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames =[NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Man%d.png", i]]];
    }

        CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];    



    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames2 =[NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames2 addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Man_up%d.png", i]]];

    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim2 = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames2 delay:0.1f];  



    //Create the sprite and run the animation                    
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.gameMan = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Man1.png"];

    _gameMan.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    self.walkAction2 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim2 restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    //[_Man runAction:_walkAction
    //[self addChild:spriteSheet];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_gameMan];

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

}
return self;
}

-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 
                                           swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
return YES;
}
//Methods for controlling the animation

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
//determine touch location  
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];       
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

//set velocity, time it takes for the sprite across the iPhone screen
float manVelocity = 480.0/4.0;
//figure out amount moved in X and Y
CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub(touchLocation, _gameMan.position);
//Figure out actual length moved
float distanceToMove = ccpLength(moveDifference);
//Figure out how long move will take
float moveDuration = distanceToMove / manVelocity;
//if moving other direction, flip direction of sprite
if (moveDifference.x < 0) {
    _gameMan.flipX = YES;
} else {
    _gameMan.flipX = NO;
}
```

> **This is the part that matters --- between here**

```
if (abs(moveDifference.x) > abs(moveDifference.y)) {

    [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction];

else {

    [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction2];  
}
```

**to here!**

```
[_gameMan stopAction:_moveAction];

if (!_moving) {
    [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction];
}


self.moveAction = [CCSequence actions:                          
                   [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
                   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(manMoveEnded)],
                   nil];

[_gameMan runAction:_moveAction];   
_moving = TRUE;

}

-(void)manMoveEnded {
[_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction];
_moving = FALSE;

}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
self.gameMan = nil;
self.walkAction = nil;
self.walkAction2 = nil;

// don't forget to call "super dealloc"
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you put the error log please? It can help us to target the issue.

Comment: @Yannick.     The simulator loads the animation and lets me touch click in a Y axis direction. The if I click in a different axis (ie;x) then it crashed the test, so it's nearly running. I know it's a simple fix that's what's bugging me.  Anyway, the log is posted below. "runaction": action is already running is likely it right?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hkkQgKuQ                                 Thx    Richg3d

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the _walkAction and the _walkAction2 before to run them.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'runAction: Action already
>   running'

This line means that the action is already running and cocos2d can't run it one more time. So before to run each action, you have to be sure that it's already finished or stop it.
The fix should look like this:

```
if (abs(moveDifference.x) > abs(moveDifference.y)) {
    [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction];
    [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction];
else {
    [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction2];
    [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction2];
}
```

Comment: Thx for your help. Finally getting time to catch up with things here.  OK,I added your code fix, and ran the app,it crashed again. Then I modified the order and changed to :`if (abs(moveDifference.x) > abs(moveDifference.y)) {
  
  if (moveDifference.x > 0)
  
  [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction];
  [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction];
 }
 else {
  
  [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction2];
  [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction2];`                  It then runs but inconsistently. But I'm pleased it at least runs.   anyway. Here's now the problem;

Comment: 1) the animation changes to the different pose when "y axis" it clicked, only when sprite finished moving, not when it starts changing direction. 2) Sprite moves on the X axis and changes it's animation frame to the other pose when it's stops (ie; the wrong L and R pose)   I tried adding some other code fixes to have some control over the last frames but nothing worked yet. It seems, maybe, I have  to add an update function of some kind to check the states of the sprite frames as they move X and Y, or add some changes to the moveAction method below ie:

Comment: `[_gameMan stopAction:_moveAction];
 
 if (!_moving) {
  [_gameMan runAction:_walkAction];
    
 }
 
 
 self.moveAction = [CCSequence actions:                          
        [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
        [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(manMoveEnded)],
        nil];
 
 [_gameMan runAction:_moveAction];   
 _moving = TRUE;
 
}

-(void)manMoveEnded {
 
    [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction];
 
    _moving = FALSE;
`

Comment: OK got it working.All I needed to do (or forgot to do) was add to the last declaration in the above method group. So this is now `-(void)manMoveEnded {
 
    [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction];
 [_gameMan stopAction:_walkAction2];
 
    _moving = FALSE;` making sure the second walkAction2 animation frames have also stopped moving. The L/R and U/D now run as they should.

Comment: However, the sequence will still crash if I click and change the sprites direction too quickly and it gets caught out before the frame loop has finished. Then it calls an exception throwing the "runAction is already running" error log. So. now need to find a way to check if the touch recognizes that this, and resets the runAction some how. Thx Again.